# How to add rows in HTML Table using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to add rows dynamically at runtime using Jquery. At beginning table don't have any records. When user click the `ADD Button` it has to add the rows. 
[image: Watch this picture]

When user click **ADD Button** the operator dropdown list box value and Filter values should add in that table row.

Here what I tried
**Jquery CODE**

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {

   // $("#queryTable tr:last").after("<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>");
    $('#queryTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>Record1</tr><tr>Record2</tr>');
});
```

I tried both lines. But it doesn't make any sense.
Thanks

**HTML Code**

```
 <table class="table table-hover " id="queryTable">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Field Name</th>
             <th>Values</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Mark</td>  //Please ignore these two records. At beginning the table will be empty
             <td>Otto</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Jacob</td>
             <td>Thornton</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: @locateganesh, [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input string HTML is incorrect. As of now you have no `TD` element thus content is not displayed. However its appended and exists in DOM

```
'<tr><td>Record1</td><td>Record2</td></tr>
```

instead of

```
'<tr>Record1</tr><tr>Record2</tr>'
```

```js
$('#queryTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>Record1</td><td>Record2</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover" id="queryTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Field Name</th>
      <th>Values</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct jQuery code to add HTML elements is:

```
$('#queryTable tbody').append('<tr><td>Record1</td><td>Record2</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Add Rows Dynamically</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        });


    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add">

    <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body> 
</html>
```

It may help you.